# Linear Algebra - Subspace test and proving linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering if someone could give me a bump in the right direction, I am not sure if my answers are right. Also, you know of any tips for the future when dealing with these types of questions.

For any non-negative integer k, let C^k(R) denote the real vector space of all continuous functions f:R→R such that the derivatives f′,f′′,...,f^(k) exist and are continuous.

(a) Show that the set U of all functions f ∈ C^2(R) such that f′′ + f′ + f = 0 (1) forms a subspace.

U is non-empty because there exists a zero function (f=0) that satisfies equation (1)

Let u and v be in U, (u+v)''+(u+v)'+(u+v) = (u''+u'+u)+(v''+v'+v)=0+0=0 thus showing U is closed under addition

let c be a scalar (cf)''+(cf)'+(cf)=c(f''+f'+f)=c0=0 thus showing U is closed under scalar multiplication

(b) Prove that the list  1, x, |x|  is linearly independent in C^0(R).

In C^0(R), f=0 c1+cx+c|x|=0 thus c=0 to satisfy this equation. Proving they are linearly independent.

Comment: For (b), don’t forget that the weights of 1,x,|x| need not be the same in value.  $1,x,|x|$ is independent  if and only if $c_1(1)+c_2 x+c_3|x|=0$ for all $x$  only when $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part $a$ seems ok.

For part $b$,

Suppose $$c_1 + c_2x+c_3|x|=0$$

If $x=0$, you should be able to evaluate the value of $c_1$.

$\forall x>0$, then $$c_1+(c_2+c_3)x=0$$

In particular, you can let $x=1$.

$\forall x <0$, $$c_1 +(c_2-c_3)x=0$$

In particular you let let $x=-1$.

Try solving to solve for $c_1, c_2, c_3$.